# Соединение двух роликов в Moviepy

Tags: python, видео

Такая проблема: скрещиваю два видео файла в один, на выходе получается тот что был первым в списке, нормально отображается, а второй вообще полное искажение. В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить? (у файлов разное разрешение, но подгонять каждый раз не вариант, так как все ролики разные и их много, поэтому в идеале все это делать циклом)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что у роликов разное разрешение, для корректной работы нужны ролики с одинаковым разрешением.